# React Ref Api's

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am following video tutorials by Max on Udemy and in one of the lectures he is trying to explain *Ref Api's in react 16.3*

So here is what he did, Inside on of the container class (not App.js) he created a property known as `this.lastref = React.createRef();` and then created a ref tag in return JSX code which looks like this `ref={this.lastref}` **(This is the parent component)**

Now in **child component** he created a method which looks like this

```
myFocus () {
 this.lastref.current.focus() 
 }
```

and then in parent component, he again did something like this in **componentDidMount lifecycle**

```
  componentDidMount() {
this.lastref.current.myFocus()
}
```

Now here are two questions which I have.

**[Question Part]**

**First**: How can he use this.lastref in child component? Is this because of the uni-directional (or one directional) flow from Parent to child **`(this.lastPersonRef  is referred from ref={this.lastPersonRef}`** ?

**Second**: `myFocus` I believe happens to be static method so shouldn't he initiate it before using it?

**[Code Example]**

**Here is what Parent Component should look like** -> [person.js]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Person from './persons/person-s';

class Cpersons extends Component {
this.lastref = React.createRef()

  componentDidMount() {
this.lastref.current.myFocus()
}

render (
return {
<Person
        key={el.id}
        click={this.props.cpdelete.bind(index)}
        ref={this.lastref}
        name={el.name}
        age={el.age}
        changed={(event) => this.props.cpchanged(event, el.id)} />
      });
    }
  }

export default Cpersons
```

and **this should be my child component** -> [person-s.js]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Cppersons extends Component {

 myFocus () {
 this.lastref.current.focus() 
 }

 render() {

 //something

 return (

 <div> Something </div>

   )
  }
}
export default Cppersons;
```

Comment: Can you clarify something? Is the `Cppersons` component being exported out of your child component supposed to be your `Person` component in your parent component?

Comment: @MaxBaldwin, Yes

Answer (score 0):

`ref` has changed a lot in the `React` world and documentation regarding it is wildy different. I suggest you use the callback method.

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.otherComponentRef = null; // Will be set after the first render
    }
    render() {
        return [
            <OtherComponent ref={el => this.otherComponentRef = el} />,
            <ChildComponent reference={this.otherComponentRef} />
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand the callback method previously being used but since Max was teaching the new ref API's in 16.3 (along with the forward API's), I thought about learning that as well

Answer (score 0):

> First: How can he use this.lastref in child component? Is this because
>   of the uni-directional (or one directional) flow from Parent to child
>   (this.lastPersonRef  is referred from ref={this.lastPersonRef} ?

when a ref is created inside a class component like this,

```
this.myRef = React.CreateRef();
```

`this.myRef` is assigned a `null` value. Later when the component is mounted, React assigns `this.myRef` an object with the `current` property making `this.myRef.current` an object containing *either*:

1. the ***dom element*** that the ref is attached to, or
2. the ***component*** that the ref is attached

In your code, `lastref` is attached to the `Person` component like so,

```
<Person ref={this.lastref} .../>
```

which at

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.lastref.current.myFocus()
}
```

React assigns the `Person` instance (component) to `this.lastref.current`, like this

```
// ~ with a bit of React magic under the hood
this.lastref.current = new Person();
```

Since `myFocus` is a method on the instance, it can be called by `this.lastref.current.myFocus()`

I encourage you to read more about **React Ref** and its expected behavior from [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). If you find yourself stuck, you can read about how [class inheritance](https://javascript.info/class-inheritance) work in Javascript which gives more insight to what is going on behind the scenes.

> Second: myFocus I believe happens to be static method so shouldn't he
>   initiate it before using it?

it's really just the syntax being used from a different Javascript specification

```
class P {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.myRef = props.myRef
  }
  myFocus() {
    console.log(this.myRef)
  }
}
```

is equivalent to

```
class P {
  myFocus() {
    console.log(this.props.myRef)
  }
}
```

in the eyes of the babel-loader from [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/) which transpiles the Javascript in a typical React application created with create-react-app. `myFocus` will be a method of the Instance when it is instantiated in both cases.